# Dragging an axes with a mouse within a figure: Matlab Gui Guide

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

The purpose of the class is to allow the user to click on an image(i.e axes) and drag it across the figure. When a mouse click is detected, the function detects which axes the mouse location lies within and initiates 'windowbuttonmotionfcn' which calls up a function 'movit'. The purpose of function 'movit' is to drag the axes selected as the mouse moves while the mouse button is down.

```
    function Mclicked(this, src, event)
        % get location of mouse click on the gui
         set(gca,'units','pix') ;
         mousePositionData = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint')
         this.x = mousePositionData(1,1);
         this.y = mousePositionData(1,2);

        %get origin position of all axes within the figure
        set(gca,'units','pix') ;
        AxesHandle=findobj(gcf,'Type','axes');
        pt1 = get(AxesHandle,{'Position','tightinset'}); % [left bottom right top] 

        %get the axes that mouse as clicked on and it in Values as a mat
            set(gcf,'windowbuttonmotionfcn',@( src, event) movit(this,src, event));
            set(gcf,'windowbuttonupfcn',@( src, event) stopmovit(this, src, event));   
        end
    end
```

I stored the original position of the mouse when it was first clicked in variable x and y. The algorithm below gets the new position of the mouse when the button is down and calculates the difference/distance between these two mouse movements. This difference is added to get the new position of the axes.

```
    function movit(this, src, event)
        %get location of new mouse position on the gui
        set(gca,'units','pix') ;
        mousePositionData = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint')
        this.x2 = mousePositionData(1,1);
        this.y2 = mousePositionData(1,2);
        this.distancex= this.x2-this.x;
        this.distancey= this.y2-this.y;
        %get the new location of the image.
        this.x2=this.Values(1,1)+this.distancex;
        this.y2=this.Values(1,2)+this.distancey;

        set(gca,'Position',[this.x2 this.y2 this.h this.w]); %x y h w
        drawnow;
    end
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the axes does not move adjacent to the mouse. For example, when the mouse button is down and the mouse is moving down or even up, **the image/axes moves downwards and disappears**. It does not move alongside the mouse cursor.

I did a test to verify if the `set(gca,'Position',[...]); %x y h w` is working correctly by moving across the figure using a counter which I increased by 1  and added the value to the original position. The axes moved as expected and visible to the user.Therefore, `set(gca,'Position',[...]); %x y h w`works fine. However, I am unsure what the error is . I assume its related to the calculations or a piece of code that I suppose to call up.

Comment: what is `this.Values`?

Comment: It is the position of the axes that the user clicked on. It a mat and stores [x ,y, h, w].

Comment: This is obtained from variable pt1 that holds all axes location.

Comment: I removed the ambiguous [guide] tag from your question, [matlab-guide] which you already had is the right one. Please read at least the short tag description of tags you're going to use for a question.

Comment: Thank you. However, still stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `mousePositionData = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint')` gets the coordinates of the mouse position within the axes. However, we need to get the mouse position within the figure or gui. Therefore, I changed gca to gcf.

In addition, I found that the x and y coordinates needed to be interchanged. `set(gca,'Position',[this.y2 this.x2 this.h this.w]); %x y h w`

The image now mouse alongside the mouse cursor. There still needs to be minor adjustments to perfect it.